# MySQL result to large

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 Tables, which both have about 300000 values. Because of technical reasons, we cannot match directly on the timestamp or onn one unique ID.

But we would like to fetch this result:

```
SELECT * FROM adsDelivered
         JOIN pageViews ON (
            adsDelivered.session = pageViews.session and 
            adsDelivered.referer = pageViews.referer and 
            abs(unix_timestamp(adsDelivered.timeCreated) - unix_timestamp(pageViews.timeCreated)) <= 5
         ) 
         WHERE pageViews.timeCreated >= '2013-03-21 00:00:00' and 
               pageViews.timeCreated <= '2013-03-21 23:59:59' 
         LIMIT 100
```

The feedback is to large and takes to long time.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I don't know what is your question

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend doing an EXPLAIN PLAN on the query.  If you see a TABLE SCAN, you'll know that you have to rewrite the query so that you use indexes effectively.

I'm guessing it's the `timeCreated` that's killing you, because you have to scan each and every JOIN row to see which one satisfies the WHERE clause.

Having some operation that cuts down the size of the set you need to scan would help a great deal.  Using indexes would also help.  Make sure the columns in the WHERE clause are indexed properly, then rewrite the query so it takes advantage of them.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can find a way to add an index to your data, there is no way to speed things up.

At the moment your overhead is that you are calling abs and unix_timestamp for each potential match as you scan through both tables.

My only suggestion to explain the plan and see what is happening, it may be suboptimal optimisation, and you may be able to improve things by not using join, and using where clauses instead like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM adsDelivered, pageViews
WHERE adsDelivered.session = pageViews.session
AND adsDelivered.referer = pageViews.referer
AND abs(unix_timestamp(adsDelivered.timeCreated) - unix_timestamp(pageViews.timeCreated)) <= 5
AND pageViews.timeCreated >= '2013-03-21 00:00:00'
AND pageViews.timeCreated <= '2013-03-21 23:59:59' 
LIMIT 100
```